# page layout destroyed due to IE9 fonts too large for <h2>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

The page layout is fine in all browsers but IE9.

We use a block-style layout on the page and a width of 660px, centered.

In keeping with the 660px max width, I set a width for h2 of 660px 
which is fine in all browers except (surprise surprise) on IE9 the h2 font is HUGE and runs off the right
of the 660px layout by a huge amount.

Can I change the verbiage in the h2 to alleviate this (shorten the text)?

Nope.  The verbiage on the page is not my purview -- someone else's job ('UE' gal).

This is my  CSS:

```
    h2 {
        width: 660px;
    }
```

That width of 660px is used in other divs on the page and provides a visually appealing 'block layout' on the page.

But on the landing page, the text inside of one of the h2 tags -- the h2 text is massively larger on IE9 so the 660px width is exceeded by the large IE9's h2 font size.

Here is an example of an offending line:

```
   <h2 class="grayDecorative">Make your Relics visible on our site now! -- OurSite!</h2>
```

Here is the 'grayDecorative' style:

```
   .grayDecorative
   {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background-image: url('images/chromishbg.gif');
      background-repeat: repeat-x;    
   }
```

This style fills in the h2 with a visually appealing gradient background behind the text.

I'm thinking to solve this by having a 'conditional-for-IE9' that uses, say -- an h3 tag instead of the h2 tag -- but **only** on IE9.

How can I make the html conditional to use an h3 for IE?

Comment: Based on the info you gave, the first thing I would look into is making sure you have expressly declared the `font-size` for the heading tags (don't leave it up to browser defaults). In the above css there is not a size declared for either the `h2` or the class `.grayDecorative`. That may solve your issue with IE (and standardize the look across browsers).

Comment: instead of having a fixed width, use a percentage of the width. it always makes the text flow on all screen sizes.

Comment: We have already tried setting the h2's to have **font-size:16pt**  and the IE9 16pt font is larger by far, running past the max 660px width but looking fine elsewhere (FF for example).  Could our **font-family: Arial, sans-serif** style in *grayDecorative* cause this?  Maybe the IE9 browser's handling of Arial is different?

Comment: No change -- I removed the **font-family: Arial** from the *.grayDecorative* class and it had zero effect.  Despite the 16pt font setting in the h2 -- the h2 font on IE9 is much bigger.

Comment: For screen display, it is better to set sizing in either `em` or `px`, since `pt` is a print scale. Have you checked font sizing using one of those units to see if it is more standardized?

Comment: Oh the hopefulness.  I tried 24px and I tried 1.5em inside the **h2** style.  Oh man I was hoping -- *dashed on the rocks of Hell.*  I was rightfully hopeful because I always use 'pt' for fonts.  For both px and em, IE9'S h2 font is huge. Balmer!!!

Answer (score 1):

I want to post the discovery I made that led to a solution.

I and others thought that using the following style should make the font size the same for the **h2** tag's text on IE and FF et al:

```
     h2
     {
         width: 660px;
         font-size: 20px;
     }
```

Setting the same **font-size**  for the **h2** tag should have done the trick.  BUT IT DIDN'T. 
For the same **font-size: 20px** above in the **h2** tag, the IE text font was much bigger.

Well I got lucky when I noticed -- other text elements on the same page were the exact same size on FF and IE9.
*But these tags were not h2* -- they were **anchors** mostly and a couple **label** tags.

The following text style generated text in the *exact same size* on IE9 and Firefox -- but note that 
the tag below is not the *h2* tags which is the one I was having text-sizing problems with:

```
 .pageTopRowTextStyle
 {
      color:RGB(255,255,255); 
      text-decoration:none;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;    
 }

 <a class="pageTopRowTextStyle" href="oursite.com">
              This text size was the same in IE9 and FF</a>
```

Here's what I discovered.  Mind you this is what we found with IE9.
You cannot reliable reconcile cross-browser text-size difference if the **h2** tag is involved.
I didn't check the other header tags (h1, h3, h4, etc).

I'm assuming the same issue.

While using the **font-size: 20px;** setting for a style on **h2** DOES make a difference -- say, if you increase to 25px or down to 15px -- you can see the font size changing on both  IE9 and FF ---

-- the **h2** tag is not responding in the same way to the **font-size ??px** across FF and IE9.

With the **h2** tag -- a  *font-size:16px* on IE9 is bigger the same *font-size:16px* for an **h2** on Firefox.
That's not true with other tags though -- **label** and **anchor** tags render the same size on both browsers.

So we just shitcanned the **h2** tag and we are now using a **label** tag in place of the **h2** tag and now the font sizes on FF and IE9 are **identical**:

```
   .h2XtraStyle
   {
      /*width: 660px;  LABEL doesn't recognize 'width' so we used &nbsp; padding */
      font-size: 20px;
   }
```

Here is a cross-browser **h2** tag -- looks the same on IE9 and FF

```
    <br />
    <label class="h2XtraStyle">Make your Relics visible on our site now! -- OurSite! 
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </i></label>
    <br />
```

I don't really know why the **h2** tag's font sizing is handled differently in IE9 but the workaround is not to use it at all.
Our solution is not very elegant but it did the job.

Comment: I think there is something with _your particular code_ that is the issue. When I [run a test case](http://jsfiddle.net/M8gRg/10/), I see very little variation at all between FF and IE9. Certainly not a "huge" difference.

Comment: I can't rule it out.  However the **h2** tag is the only tag being affected by this difference, and -- the **h2** tag is not in our one-and-only CSS stylesheet file.  And we have no conditional comments, no 'browser detect' code differences at all.  So why wouldn't FF look the same -- if it's the *exact same* code?

Comment: The only answer I can give to your question is _different defaults_. But other than font-size, I'm stumped at the moment as to what else would cause it. A question and a request of you: 1) when you look at my test case link in my last comment, do you see a difference between FF and IE9? 2) Could you post a screen shot of the difference you are seeing between FF and IE9?